# Query text to show sites a user can access using Search Results SP2013

Tags: search, authorization

I'm looking to show all sites a user has access to through the Search Results web part in SharePoint 2013. I have added it with the query text:

```
contentclass:"STS_Site" contentclass:"STS_Web"
```

..but there are sites showing up for users that do not have Read permissions. Am I missing something in the query? Is there another way to show authorized results only?

Comment: I think there must be some permission parameter should be there for this.

Comment: Does your default crawl account have more than READ access? For example is it the FARM account rather than a crawl account?

Comment: Yes. I'm using spadmin which should have full control