# DoesUserHavePermissions not working

Tags: 2013, permissions, spservices, visual-studio-2012

I have tried multiple different ways to get this code to work. I will post both methods of code. Neither ones work. The idea is to get all the "Sites a user can access", and create a hyperlink within a visual web part. We need to get each web application the site collections, and then each web below NOT including subsites.

The environment is SharePoint 2013 OnPremise. This is a FarmSolution.

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();
        SPServiceCollection services = SPFarm.Local.Services;

        foreach (SPService eachService in services)
        {
            if (eachService is SPWebService)
            {
                SPWebService webService = (SPWebService)eachService;
                foreach (SPWebApplication webApp in webService.WebApplications)
                {
                    if (!webApp.DisplayName.Contains("MySites"))
                    {
                        SPSiteCollection siteColl = webApp.Sites;
                        foreach (SPSite site in siteColl)
                        {
                            site.CatchAccessDeniedException = false;
                            if (site.RootWeb.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName, SPBasePermissions.Open))
                                try
                                {
                                    HyperLink hyp = new HyperLink();
                                               hyp.ID = "dynamicLinks";
                                               hyp.Text = "Link";
                                               hyp.CssClass = "SitesAccessLinks";
                                               hyp.NavigateUrl = site.Url.ToString();
                                               this.Controls.Add(hyp);
                                               foreach (SPWeb childweb in site.RootWeb.Webs)
                                               {
                                                   if (childweb.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName, SPBasePermissions.Open))
                                                   {
                                                       try
                                                       {
                                                           HyperLink clink = new HyperLink();
                                                           clink.ID = "DynamicLinks";
                                                           clink.Text = "link";
                                                           clink.CssClass = "WebAccessLinks";
                                                           clink.NavigateUrl = childweb.Url.ToString();
                                                           this.Controls.Add(clink);
                                                       }
                                                       finally
                                                       {
                                                           childweb.Dispose();
                                                       }
                                                   }
                                                   site.CatchAccessDeniedException = false;
                                               }
                                }
                                finally
                                {
                                    site.Dispose();
                                }
```

The code above returns a permissions issue. Without debugging, the website returns 403 The website declined to show this webpage. The code below does as well.

```
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();
        SPServiceCollection services = SPFarm.Local.Services;

        foreach (SPService eachService in services)
        {
            if (eachService is SPWebService)
            {
                SPWebService webService = (SPWebService)eachService;
                foreach (SPWebApplication webApp in webService.WebApplications)
                {
                    if (!webApp.DisplayName.Contains("MySites"))
                    {
                        SPSiteCollection siteColl = webApp.Sites;
                        foreach (SPSite site in siteColl)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                site.CatchAccessDeniedException = false;
                                using (SPSite indiSite = new SPSite(site.Url))
                                {
                                    using (SPWeb oWebSite = indiSite.OpenWeb())
                                    {
                                      if (!oWebSite.IsRootWeb)
                                        {

                                            if (oWebSite.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName, SPBasePermissions.EnumeratePermissions))
                                            {
                                                SPBasePermissions permissionToCheck = SPBasePermissions.Open;
                                                Label lbl9 = new Label();
                                                lbl9.Text = "WOLOLololo";
                                                this.Controls.Add(lbl9);
                                                if (oWebSite.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName, permissionToCheck))
                                                {
                                                    Label hyp = new Label();
                                                    hyp.ID = "dynamicLinks";
                                                    hyp.Text = oWebSite.Title.ToString();
                                                    hyp.CssClass = "SitesAccessLinks";
                                                    ///   hyp.NavigateUrl = "https://google.com";
                                                    this.Controls.Add(hyp);
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                Label lbl11 = new Label();
                                                lbl11.Text = "Can't enumerate";
                                                this.Controls.Add(lbl11);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            Label lbl8 = new Label();
                                            lbl8.Text = oWebSite.Title.ToString();
                                            this.Controls.Add(lbl8);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            finally
                            {
                                site.CatchAccessDeniedException = true;
                            }
```

Comment: You can do that pretty easily with search by looking for STS_Site, it is automatically security trimmed and you don't have the expense of walking down the entire web app to find stuff. Recent question on a similar vein: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160644/show-users-a-list-of-sites-they-can-access/160645#160645

Comment: How do I implement this?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to list sites a user has access to is do a search for: `contentclass:STS_Web`

If you really really want to implement the slow way then you need to use `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` as you'll come across web applications/site collection the current user doesn't have access to

Comment: I'm not seeing how I implement this