# How to display all the site collections on a page?

Tags: site-collection

I need to display all the website from a given web application (sites.inside.ml) to users. Are the following steps correct?

1. Create a page
2. Drop a CEWP (content editor web part)
3. Create a jQuery based code to bring back all the sites from a given web app with links to it.

Is there a better way?

Comment: seems perfect to me!

Comment: Is there any ready made jQuery for this so I am not re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: then you should ask for the ready made thing! Unfortunately it is not the right place of it!

Comment: use the content search web part. no need to write code then

Answer (score 1):

You are in the right path. Use the search REST API. The below code from [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166382/displaying-all-sites-a-user-has-access-to-across-an-entire-web-application/166398#166398) should get you started.

```
    <button id='btnGetSites'>Get Sites</button>

<div id='list'>

</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>


(function(){
    var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
    var url = siteUrl + "/_api/search/query?querytext='(contentclass:STS_Site OR contentclass:STS_Web)'";
    $('#btnGetSites').click(function(){
        console.log('start..');

        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: success,
            error: error
        });

        function success(data){
            var html = '';

            $.each(data.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows, function(index, row){                
                var title = '';
                var url = '';
                $.each(row.Cells, function(i, obj){             
                    if(obj.Key === 'Title'){
                        html += obj.Value; 
                    }
                    else if(obj.Key === 'Path'){
                        html += ": " + obj.Value + "<br/>";
                    }               
                });         
            });

            $('#list').append(html);
        }
        function error(err){
            console.log(err);
        }       
        return false;
    });

}());

</script>
```

Comment: This code is partial solution. It requires custom VS code.

Comment: For what purpose do you need custom VS code?