# Can I get list of all sharepoint site specific user have access on?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, administration

Can I get list of all sharepoint site specific user have access on ? Like i want to get list of all type of SharePoint site in my O365 tenant, user have some kind of permission on.

I need this work to be done as a part of IT that when a user leave remove user from all sharepoint he/she have any kind of permission on. I looked for some script but all provides info for single site but that would be too time taking if i will run script for each sharepoint site every time a user leaves company. Please help also let me know if there is any other way to achieve same apart from Powershell script.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying All sites a User Has access to, Across an Entire Web Application!](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166382/displaying-all-sites-a-user-has-access-to-across-an-entire-web-application)

Comment: Do you want for specific user or All the users?